# How to format an excel cell as a year, month?

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I have the following value:

```
18
```

How can I get Excel to show this as `1 year, 6 months` or something similar?

Comment: You know you're a *NIX programmer when you see the word `excel` and render it as `execl`. After all, people read letters, not words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your value is in A1, you can use the following formula to display it as years, months:

```
=IF(A1>11, INT(A1/12) & " year" & IF(INT(A1/12)<>1, "s", ""), "") 
& IF(MOD(A1,12) > 0, IF(A1>11, ", ", "") & MOD(A1, 12) & " month" 
& IF(MOD(A1,12)<>1, "s", ""), "")
```

This will show the following types of values:

> 1 year
>   6 months
>   1 month
>   1 year, 4 months
>   2 years, 11 months

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
=INT(A1/12) & " years " & MOD(A1,12) & " months"
```